# Is there an IPN sent after DoExpressCheckoutPayment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, express-checkout

After we do DoExpressCheckoutPayment - resulting in payment status `Completed` or failing with some other status - is there any IPN sent from PayPal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, DECP sends IPN notifications.  If you're not getting them make sure you have IPN enabled either through your profile or by the NOTIFYURL parameter in your request.  Then check the IPN History in your PayPal account and your web server logs for details on whether or not the script is getting hit or not, and if there might be an error keeping it from running correctly.